# How can I remove the Status = Pending with the Date of less than the currentdate in a select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

How can I remove the Status = Pending with the Date of less than the currentdate in my query... This should be a select statement

```
Status Date
Pending 9/5/2014  
Pending 9/30/2014
Complete 8/28/2014
Error 8/20/2014
```

Comment: some more description please!!

Comment: Are you deleting or selecting from table?

Comment: Selecting Table... Updated the question and body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you wish to remove the data where Status is 'Pending' before the current date, I assume you want to delete that data. Here's the deletion query.

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE status = 'Pending'
AND date < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

However, since you mention that you need a select statement, here's the select query excluding records where Status is 'Pending' before the current date.

```
SELECT status, date FROM my_table 
WHERE status <> 'Pending'
AND date < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

(The above query will incorrectly skip all records where Status is 'Pending') The next query should work exactly as intended.

```
SELECT status, date FROM my_table 
EXCEPT
SELECT status, date FROM my_table 
WHERE status = 'Pending'
AND date < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

Comment: Hi, I need to get rid of the date before the current date with the pending status.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT status, date FROM Test 
WHERE status <> 'Pending'
AND date < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/755f0/1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below. I think it should do the work. If you are changing status column only then the below should work.

```
    SELECT  CASE  WHEN date < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) and status ='Pending' 
    THEN 'YouNEwStatus' 
      ELSE
          status END AS status, date
      FROM  
            MYTable
```

And if you are hiding the rows. The query mentioned by the gentleman above should work.

```
SELECT status, date FROM Test 
WHERE status <> 'Pending'
AND date < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```